# How to properly use if not statement with twig

Tags: twig

I have been trying to figure out how to use the `if not` clause with Twig template engine.

According to the [documents](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html):

> You can also use *not* to check for values that evaluate to *false*:

So I'm trying to use it like this:

```
{% if not signed_in %}
 You are not signed in.
{% endif %}
```

And `signed_in` comes from a middleware. Looking like this:

```
    if (!$this->container->auth->check()) {
        /* Render a Sign-up */
        return $this->container->view->render($response, 'subscriber/index.twig', ['signed_in' => false]);
    }
```

So if I `{{ dump(signed_in) }}` when I'm not signed in it returns `false`. But when I'm signed in, `singed_in` returns `null`.

[image: Not signed in left. Signed in on right]

The current solution I'm going with is `{% if signed_in is defined %}`, but that is actually not what I'm looking for, or is it?

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you to use:
`{% if signed_in == true %}` or `{% if signed_in == false%}`

This is the twig comportment:

```
{% set testTrue = true %}
{% set testFalse = false %}
{% set testNull = null %}
{% set testString = "something" %}


{% if testTrue %} {# true #}
{% if testFalse %}{# false#}
{% if testNull %} {# false#}
{% if testString %} {# true #}

{% if not testTrue %}{# false#}
{% if not testFalse %}{# true#}
{% if not testNull %} {# false   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! #}
{% if not testString %} {# false#}

{% if testTrue == true %} {# true #}
{% if testFalse == true  %} {# false#}
{% if testNull == true  %} {# false#}
{% if testString == true  %} {# true #}

{% if not testTrue == true %} {# false#}
{% if not testFalse == true  %} {# true #}
{% if not testNull == true  %} {# true #}
{% if not testString == true  %} {# false#}
```

other tests good to know

```
{% if testTrue == 1 %} {# true #}
{% if testFalse == 1  %} {# false#}
{% if testTrue == "1" %} {# true #}
{% if testFalse == "1"  %} {# false#}
```

Comment: Why does `not testNull` return false?

Comment: i don't know the internals, i just did all those tests manually

Answer (score 7):

Twig != is a comparison operator.

```
The following comparison operators are supported in any expression: ==, !=, <, >, >=, and <=
```

You can use != to compare any two things that php lets you compare, and what you get back is a boolean.

Twig not is a logic operator. (so are and and or)

```
not: Negates a statement.
```